# kinetic.js layer width after scaling

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Does kinetic.js Layer object scale its width?

After scaling whole layer and trying to obtain width by getWidth() method, I get what I set on layer instantiation. Is that intentional kinetic.js behavior?

http://jsfiddle.net/qHmZz/

```js
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container : 'container',
    width: 300,
    height: 300
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    width: 300,
    height: 300
});

var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: 150,
        y: 150,
        radius: 30,
        fill: 'green',
});

layer.add(circle);

stage.add(layer);

$('#message').append( 'width before scale: ' + layer.getWidth() + "</br>");
// 300

layer.setScale(0.9);
layer.draw();

$('#message').append('width after scale: ' + layer.getWidth());
//300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the intended behavior.

If you want the scaled width:

```
$('#message').append('width after scale: ' + layer.getWidth() * layer.getScale().x);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qHmZz/2/